# Why is framework version 7.3 not available for download on the Sencha Support Site?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Last week, I downloaded Sencha Architect version 4.2.9.  It installed Sencha Cmd version 7.3 and version 7.3 of the ExtJS framework as a part of the installation process.  However, 7.3 is not available as a separate download on the Support site as it would typically be.  Why is that?

Comment: You would need to contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

Current download is only 7.2.0.66 - If you got 7.3 I'd say that was an accidental leak of 7.3 if you got it...

I'm only getting

both support portal and npm are only supplying 7.2 series

Would love a copy of 4.2.9 if you have one... I can't seem to get that either.

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS 73 is now available on support portal.